# What is wrong here?Why is my Javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

New to this and just starting a little bit of JavaScript. I cannot work out why the following isn't working on render. The html is there but I get no text when the button is clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Js to Validate Data</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Can JS Validate User input?</h1>

<p> Please enter number between 1 and 21:</p>
<input id="nums" type="number">

<button type="button" onclick="chkData()">Verify Entry</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function chkData() {
        var x, text;
        
    x = document.getElementById("nums").value;
        
        if (isNaN(x) || x<1 || x> 21)  {
            text = "Invalid Input, try again!";
        }
        else {
            text = "All Ok!";
        }
        
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen which is not happening? If you are expecting your HTML to change, can you point to which exact line of code you thought would be updating your HTML? Right now you are creating a `text` variable which you never do anything with.

Comment: So when the 'Verify Entry' button is clicked, text should appear to either state that the input is invalid, try again or that all ok.

Comment: And which line of code were you expecting to change your HTML to show that new text?

Comment: It's no going to change the HTML it should add to it. Or is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok, then add. Which line of code did you think would add that text to your HTML?

Comment: Well my understanding is that I have created a function right? An that this function should work on the click of the button and that if if/else statement is telling the document what to add? No?

Comment: Not quite. All of that is correct except that your code is just making a variable, not "telling the document what to add". It does not add it to the HTML automatically. The code has no idea what exact variables you want added and where you want it added - you have to be specific about where that new text should go in the page. The answer given below adds that extra line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be a little specific about what is happening. As far as i can guess you are not able to see the `text` because you are not adding it to the html. Select the div with an id `demo` and append the text using `innerText` to the div.

```js
  function chkData() {
  var x, text;     
  x = document.getElementById("nums").value;      
  if (isNaN(x) || x<1 || x> 21)  {
      text = "Invalid Input, try again!";
     }
     else {
       text = "All Ok!";
     }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerText = text;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Can JS Validate User input?</h1>

<p> Please enter number between 1 and 21:</p>
<input id="nums" type="number">

<button type="button" onclick="chkData()">Verify Entry</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This would be an ok answer if you explained what the issue was and what you did to fix it.

Comment: It is just incredibly confusing as it works when the gentleman does it on the tutorial, so I cannot work out why it doesn't work when I do the same thing.

Comment: @MacallaCraske Try re-checking your code and add the text to the html as i have shown in the snippet above :) It will work as you expect it to.

Comment: Ahh this actually makes sense to me. Thank you Mohammad. I'll give it a go.

Comment: The key is just this one line `document.getElementById('demo').innerText = text;` which you were missing.

Comment: Still not working though!

Comment: It works right here in this page - just run the example and you can see. If your own code is still not working then you either didn't make the correct update or there is something else you have not shown us.

Comment: @MacallaCraske Just copy the above code and paste it there and see if it is working

Comment: I have shown you the whole thing. Perhaps i just need to delete and rewrite the script.

Comment: @MacallaCraske Don't rewrite it. Just copy and paste. simple!

Comment: All working now! Thank you!